# Rails path helper with singular controller names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pluralize

First of all a warning: I am new to Ruby on Rails. I am creating an application and run into the problem creating a controller when the entity has the same name in plural and singular. In my case it's "fish", so I have a `Fish` model, a `FishController`, a `fish` table etc. It works just fine (surprisingly, at least to me), except when I try to use the path helper:

```
<%= link_to 'My fishes', fish_path %>
```

When I try that, rails shows me an error

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"fish"} missing required keys: [:id]
```

I know that when you have a resource `:apples`, `apples_path` would refer to the index and `apple_path(:id)` (without s) to the `show` method for a particular item. My guess about what is happening is that, when I say `fish_controller` I am referring to the `show` method, and hence the error: it is missing an ID.

My question is, how do I call the "plural" `fish_path` to go to the `index`?

And a preventive question: do you know of any other issues that I can find related to this "weirdness" with the names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- name for `fish#index` is `fish_index`
- name for `fish#show` is `fish`

So you should use:

```
<%= link_to 'My fishes', fish_index_path %>
```

And link fish's profile to:

```
<%= link_to 'Biggest Fish', fish_path(@fish) %>
```

Comment: I'm quite sure that index route helpers are never created with `(subject)_index_path`, but with an argument-less `GET (subject)_path`. In the case of fish and sheep it's rather an inflection problem. For your suggestion to work, he must name that route `get 'fish/': 'fish#index', as: 'fish_index'`.

Comment: @wiesion you can examine `rake routes` to see that `fish#index` is named as `fish_index` and it's helper is called accordingly `fish_index_path`.

Comment: tbh, i didn't set up a test right now, it's just what i remember by memory: i am quite sure there is no `_index` in index path helpers. So i'll get my laptop and make a quick try :)

Comment: @wiesion please don't comment on thing you "don't remember". As to your advice to uncomment `inflect.uncountable %w( fish sheep )`, it's not going to work, because, if you read comment in `inflections.rb` file, it says: "All of these examples are active by default", so you effectively doing nothing by removing this comment.

Comment: Just tried, you were one step ahead indeed. In case of an uncountable inflection ActiveSupport does indeed append `_index` - i never ran into such a case and didn't need it, so i was quite sure that by adding the inflection the route helper would work without `_index`.

Comment: @dimakura I just tried it and it works like a charm. I googled for hours but I couldn't find this little 'trick' anywhere. Thanks a lot! Beer is on me :)